# MySQL reset id custom id based on current year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so:

[image]

and I have this customID:

```
SELECT c.Id, CONCAT_WS('-', RIGHT(YEAR(DateCreated), 2), LPAD(c.Id,3,0)) as CustomID
```

[image]

Because it's 2021 - I now need it to reset back to `21-001`

Current output:

[image]

**Question:**

What would be an appropriate method to alter this to desired output?

**Desired**

```
21-001
21-002
```

Comment: It seems too obvious that something other than DateCreated would be part of the concatenated string. Come on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `RIGHT(YEAR(DateCreated), 2)` try `RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()), 2)`

Every time a year pass the year will be reset and you save the DateCreated.